# Unable to run notify-send from cronjob

Tags: scripts, cron, notification, notify-send

In my Kubuntu 22.04, a script run by my crontab uses `notify-send`. However, it doesn't work: there is no pop-up appearing. If I redirect the output (`stderr` in particular) of the script to a file, this error is printed:

```
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached
```

If instead I run `notify-send` directly from a cronjob,

```
0 * * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send --expire-time=0 --app-name="Test" 'Test text' 1>/tmp/out1 2>/tmp/out2
```

`out1` and `out2` are empty; however, this doesn't work as before. The pop-up does not appear.

Is there a way to make `notify-send` work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess for `notify-send` to work in a cron job you have to copy the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` from your current desktop session and set it in the cron job. Also, `notify-send` must run as the same user who is currently logged in to the desktop session.

At least that works for me.

Comment: The user is the same. After also setting `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` it works. Thank you!